# Debugging QList<double> in Visual Studio with Qt integration

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt

When I'm debugging my program, the values displayed for floating point numbers are totally wrong.

```
double a = 1.0;
QList<double> list;
list << a;
```

With this example the debbugger shows that `a` contains `1.0` that `list` contains one item, but its displayed value is rubbish (seems that is not read at the right place) -- its real value is correct anyhow if I display it in my program UI.

[Qt Visual intergation fails on QLists http://pix.gregseth.net/4b5ea2be.png](http://pix.gregseth.net/4b5ea2be.png)

Anyone had this problem and knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the knowledge of Qt's types to Visual Studio?  If not, see the information about it on [Qt's mailing list](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2005-01/thread00239-0.html) and on [this blog entry about integrating Qt and Visual Studio.](http://eecs.vanderbilt.edu/research/hmtl/wiki/pmwiki.php?n=Knowledge.Qt)

Comment: The second link seems to be the one. I'll try that at work tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: The new version (updated for Qt 4.6.1) works, even for 4.5.1. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Works as expected for me, using Qt Creator.
Have you tried running the same code with another debugger?

Comment: No, but I'd like it to work in VS given it' the IDE I have to use for this project.

Comment: I see, I was just thinking that'd be a way of knowing for sure there's nothing wrong with your code. But well, its a simple code snippet, not much room for mistakes there